# Get link from text input field and then open it with DalekJS

Tags: automated-tests, dalekjs

I have an issue where the link I need to traverse to using DalekJS that is not clickable, it is rather copy/pastable. How can I retrieve a value from an input field in the browser and then use it in a test.open() call?

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Link 1</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="http://example.com/link-1" class="start-link"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Link 2</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="http://example.com/link-2" class="start-link"></td>
        <tr>
</table>
```

In the example above I would like DalekJS to dynamically run `test.open('http://example.com/link-1');` during the progression of my test.

```
module.exports = {

    'A test case': function (test) {
        test.open('http://example.com/example-from-above.html')
        .open('http://example.com/link-1')  //This is the link I'm trying to retrieve dynamically.
        .screenshot('image.png')
        .done();
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

DalekJS does not allow reading values of HTML element synchronously and using them in the test scripts.  If you need to interact with the content of the testing page, the [`execute`](http://dalekjs.com/docs/actions.html#meth-execute) method may help.

You can try setting the window location by a function "executed in the browser":

```
module.exports = {

    'A test case': function (test) {
        test.open('http://example.com/example-from-above.html')
        // Open the URL from the first input element value
        .execute(function () {
            var input = document.querySelectorAll('.start-link')[0];
            location = input.value;
        })
        // Wait until the browser opens the page
        .waitFor(function () {
            return location.pathname.indexOf('link-1') > 0;
        })
        .screenshot('image.png')
        .done();
    }
}
```